# How do I set the callback parameter value as defined, and what value isn't defined?

Tags: javascript, code.org

please note this *is* in code.org, so code is slightly different, but it's still javascript.
I keep getting this message from this portion of code, and don't quite understand.

```
var ii = 0;
  while (ii < 4) { 
  setTimeout(callback(ii), 1000);
  ii++;
}

});
function callback(t) { 
  playSound(("key0"+(allnotelist[t]+1))+".mp3",false); 
}
```

Message in question: setTimeout() callback parameter value (undefined) is not a function

Comment: i realize now, that this isn't formatted very well, but this was a portion of code inside an onEvent function

Answer (score 1):

pass a function not a return of its

change  `setTimeout(callback(ii), 1000);` to  `setTimeout(() => callback(ii), 1000);`

Comment: Hello, I tried replacing it so it reads like ```onEvent("noteplayer", "click", function( ) {
var ii = 0;
  while (ii < 4) { 
 setTimeout(() => callback(ii), 1000);
  ii++;
}

});
function callback(t) { 
  playSound(("key0"+(allnotelist[t]+1))+".mp3",false); 
}``` now, and it doesnt work as intended, did i do something incorrect?

Comment: I don't see this to add anything to davidhu's answer.

Comment: You want to play each song after 1s, right?
try this.

``` lang-js
sequencePlay = (cb, max) => {
    let counter = 0;
    const id = setInterval(() => {
        if(counter < max){
            cb(counter);
            counter++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(id)
        }
    }, 1000)
}

sequencePlay((i) => { console.log(i) }, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you're passing the handler to setTimeout

when you do

```js
setTimeout(callback(ii), 1000);
```

what you're doing is basically

```js
setTimeout(/* returned value of callback */, 1000);
```

which by looking at the callback function definition, it returns `undefined` since you don't explicitly `return` anything. So you're doing

```js
setTimeout(undefined, 1000)
```

The way to fix the error is by creating a new function

```js
setTimeout(() => callback(ii), 1000)
```

Comment: What does ```setTimeout(() => callback(ii), 1000)``` do?

Comment: that essentially creates a new function to pass to the setTimeout